# Bad icon displayed on PWA Android/chrome splashscreen

Tags: android, google-chrome, manifest, splash-screen

This is the manifest.json I use to make appear the largest icon possible on chrome/android splashscreen for my PWA :

```json
{
    "name": "App name",
    "short_name": "App name",
    "icons": [                
        {  
          "src": "icons/touchIcon-192x192.png",
          "sizes": "192x192",  
          "type": "image/png"  
        },  
        {  
          "src": "icons/touchIcon-256x256.png",
          "sizes": "256x256",  
          "type": "image/png"  
        },  
        {  
          "src": "icons/touchIcon-384x384.png",
          "sizes": "384x384",  
          "type": "image/png"  
        },  
        {  
          "src": "icons/touchIcon-512x512.png",
          "sizes": "512x512",  
          "type": "image/png"  
        }
    ],
    "background_color": "#323A4F",
    "theme_color": "#323A4F",
    "start_url": "/?standalone",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "lang": "fr"
}
```

The problem is that chrome always displays a very very small icon at center of screen, about 48px I think...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and frustration, I found out that you must only specify the icon with 512px in the manifest or else it will use a lower DP icon as the app icon, and based on that it will use the large or small layout for the splash.
You can read more about it here: here:https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen):

> 128dp is the ideal size for the image on the splash screen as it means
>   no scaling will be applied to the image. Now we web developers don't
>   deal with dp's. We use physical pixels or CSS pixels. In the case of
>   splash screen and configuration in the manifest only physical pixels
>   are considered. 1dp is 1 physical pixel at a screen density of 160dpi.
>
> 1dp = 1px at 160 dpi.
>
> 128dp at 1x (160dpi) = 128px 128dp at 1.5x (240dpi) = 192px ( 128 * (
>   240 / 160 ) ) 128dp at 2x (320dpi) = 256px  128dp at 3x (480dpi) =
>   384px (Equivalent to Nexus 5) 128dp at 4x (640dpi) = 512px (Nexus 6 is
>   in between 3 and 4)